# Need advice with pin connection of an LCD module

Tags: short-circuit, pins

[image]

Hello. I am working on this LCD module, COG-C144MVGI-08.

Like in the image I uploaded, PIN 1, 4 and 12 are ground.

(Just in case you need the full datasheet : 
https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/COG-C144MVGI-08%20Full%20Spec.pdf)

The problem is, I overestimated the stress-tolerance of the pins and I broke PIN 1.

I think that I can just connect one of the GND pins, and it will work just fine.

Am I correct? **I leave PIN 1 and 4 unconnected. Will the module work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's impossible to answer, because these different grounds were added for a reason – typically, signal integrity.

If your cable is short and your environment low in noise and both ends can work with the slightly changed impedance, and that ground line is actually connected to the other ground lines at the module and not e.g. a dedicated power ground: maybe.

If you rely on this to be reliable: well, chances are you broke one of your device's connections and now, everything might happen.

Comment: Yeah. I tested with my multimeter and they were connected to each other. I flipped out when that happened without knowing they were GND. I guess the only way to know is to test. Thank you.

Comment: At the end, I somehow managed to solder PIN1 without problem.

Comment: So, it won't be any problem. Thank you anyhow. It came to my mind that there is a reason why there are 3 GND pins but I need an assurance.